# C# MongoDb deserialization of an abstract sub-document

Tags: c#, mongodb, serialization, deserialization, mongodb-.net-driver

Prefix: Using .net 4.6.1, C# 7, C# MongoDb 2.5.0

Issue in general:

I have a small class which contains a field of an abstract type.

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements(true)]
public sealed class FatherAlmighty
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id;

    public MyAbstract Item;
}
```

also, this `MyAbstract` is obviously an abstract class which has at least 2 inheriting classes.

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements(true)]
[BsonKnownTypes(typeof(Child1))]
public abstract class MyAbstract
{
    public string DontCare;
}

[BsonIgnoreExtraElements(true)]
public sealed class Child1 : MyAbstract
{
    public string ChildishField;
}
```

The `BsonKnownTypes` contains every single type of class inherited from `MyAbstract` but I wrote only 1 for simplicity matter.

What I need to happen: Because of architecture demands, I need to be able to add (only add) fields to `Child1` on mongo and then deploy an application version to use this value.

Problem: Whenever I add a value to document, before application deploy, im getting a deserialization issues.
For example, If I add the field `AnotherChildishField` in my document (attention to document and **not** class) with a value of "myStr", I expect everything to work by ignoring this newly added field, but errors are raining cats and dogs.

> An error occurred while deserializing the Item field of class <.....>: Element 'AnotherChildishField' does not match any field or property of class <.....>

What am I missing? I added IgnoreExtraElements for almost everything.

Comment: Interesting... it seems to work fine in with the MongoDb 2.5 package at least.

Comment: @AluanHaddad is there any info you need to further try to reproduce?

Comment: [See this gist](https://gist.github.com/aluanhaddad/a27b622170234b2359e2cf61e138e91d). I got curious when I read this question, as I had used the API but not recently.

Comment: wait. after you insert a document, you need to add the value in the document in the db. not in the class

Comment: Why does it matter? It is deserializing from a string that has a field not declared on the class. The field is not declared by the class. Or do you mean that  a different serializer is used when retrieving from the db?

Comment: you tried an intresting thing. but i have no idea why it happens..

Comment: @AluanHaddad the problem is that you're not trying to do it from the level im doing. you're just trying to deserialize the object, that should work, the problem is doing it 2 layers above in the FatherAlmighty level. I havent try to reproduce using your way, but it smth i should try.

Comment: @AluanHaddad also, when the document is serialized on mongo, it adds a _t field which represents the type and by doing what you did, the serialization is not similar